# Libopencv undefined reference to 'header'

Tags: ros, libopencv, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to compile ROS on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) following these Debian installation instructions and got to the point to compile ROS, which fails at compiling opencv with `undefined reference to 'header'`:

```
[ 97%] Built target opencv_videostab
[ 98%] Built target opencv_haartraining_engine
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_createsamples
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.6: undefined reference to `header'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_createsamples] Error 1
make[1]: *** [apps/haartraining/CMakeFiles/opencv_createsamples.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'opencv2': 
  Command '/home/ilagi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j1 -l1' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

I googled to try to figure out what header file might be missing, but unfortunately didn't get anywhere.

I hope somebody will have an idea about at least the directions to go from here.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126126/libopencv-undefined-reference-to-%27header%27/) by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on ROS Answers with karma: 218 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess I'm going to answer my own question. I don't exactly know which dependency caused this particular error, but I had recompiled ffmpeg based on the instructions provided at ariandy1.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/raspberry-pi-rasbian-opencv/ and now I managed to get ROS to compile opencv.

---

Originally posted by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) with karma: 218 on 2014-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0